# goToSlide with bxSlider not working

Tags: bxslider

I've tried many options but all of them didn't work. In the head there is this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function(){
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
                adaptiveHeight: true
        });
</script>
```

(There is more script in the head, of course there are enough } to close the script. The slider works fine, but the goToSlide does nothing.)

And now I want to jump to a slide with the goToSlide() function, if the window.location is #xyz. This is what I do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    if (window.location.href === "https://myadress.de/#link1") {
        slider.goToSlide(0);
    } 
    else if (window.location.href === "https://myadress.de/#link2") {
        slider.goToSlide(1);
    }
</script>
```

The goal is to link directly some slides from other pages.

Your help would be amazing.

// edit:
Now it works that I can slide to a specific slider. But just if I reload the page. Example: If I type https://myadress.de/#link2 into my browser, it does nothing. But if I reload exact the same page, it slides to the specific slider (it doesn't jump to the right place on the website, but this is another problem).

Comment: *"The goal is to link directly some slides from other pages."*  Page A has a bxslider and page B has a bxSlider.  You on page A and what do you want to do? being directly linked is vague in that isn't a measurable behavior. `goToSlide()` is a method that has an obvious behavior. *"Being directly linked"* isn't a behavior or result.

Comment: If I link from another page to https://myadress.de/#link2 I want to jump to the start-page (with the slider) and slide automatically to #2 of the slider. It works for me, but not at all. I will edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

We'll assume that each page bxSlider jumps to is a page on the same website. For each page you want bxSlider to jump to you can setup each slider differently or identical. The most important difference is that on each page, you use this option:

```
startSlide: {index number}
```

In the following Demo, there are:

- 5 pages.
- Each page has 2 bxSliders.
- The first slider is a normal slider.
- The second slider has a link to a corresponding page.
- Both sliders are synced to each other binded to the API event callback `onBeforeSlide` handled by a custom function `bxMove()`.
- The method `.goToSlide()` is called by `bxMove()`.
- Each pages' sliders have `startSlide` with the value of the corresponding order of its page.

---

#### Reference

**[bxSlider Options](https://bxslider.com/options/)**

**This Demo does not fully function because it features 5 pages which is beyond SO's capabilities. Go to this [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/BoJE2YrCPumIGHLtgl7n/) for a fully functional Demo.**

---

#### Test

Go to the **[Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/BoJE2YrCPumIGHLtgl7n/)** and use the top pager and the first slider conventionally. When at the desired slide, click the second slider at the bottom. It will jump to the indicated page and begin at the indicated slide.

---

### [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/BoJE2YrCPumIGHLtgl7n/)

### Demo

```js
const cfgA = {
  startSlide: 0,
  pagerCustom: '.bx-pager',
  onSlideBefore: bxMove
};
const cfgB = {
  startSlide: 0,
  controls: false,
  pager: false,
  onSlideBefore: bxMove
};

const bx = $('.bx-slider').bxSlider(cfgA);

const lx = $('.bx-linx').bxSlider(cfgB);

function bxMove($ele, from, to) {
  bx.goToSlide(to);
  lx.goToSlide(to);
  $('.bx-core a').removeClass('active');
  $('.bx-pager a').eq(to).addClass('active');
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 400 16px/1.3 Consolas;
}

.bx-wrapper {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.bx-core img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bx-core a,
.bx-core a:link,
.bx-core a:visited {
  display: table-cell;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #00c;
}

.bx-core a:hover,
.bx-core a:active {
  outline: 3px ridge cyan;
}

.bx-pager a.active {
  outline: 3px ridge tomato;
}

.bx-linx a.active+a {
  color: tomato;
}

.bx-pager,
.bx-linx {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto .75em;
  text-align: center;
}

.bx-linx {
  width: 150px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Index</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.css" />

  <style>

  </style>


</head>

<body>
  <main id='bx-core0' class='bx-core'>
    <nav class="bx-pager">
      <a data-slide-index="0" href="#/" class='active'>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/0" width="50" /></a>
      <a data-slide-index="1" href="#/">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/1" width="50" /></a>
      <a data-slide-index="2" href="#/">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/2" width="50" /></a>
      <a data-slide-index="3" href="#/">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/3" width="50" /></a>
      <a data-slide-index="4" href="#/">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/4" width="50" /></a>
    </nav>

    <ul class="bx-slider">
      <li>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/0" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/1" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/2" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/3" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people/4" />
      </li>
    </ul>

    <nav class='bx-linx'>
      <a data-slide-index="0" href="index.html"></a>
      <a data-slide-index="1" href="page1.html">➊</a>
      <a data-slide-index="2" href="page2.html">➋</a>
      <a data-slide-index="3" href="page3.html">➌</a>
      <a data-slide-index="4" href="page4.html">➍</a>
    </nav>
    <h1>Index</h1>
  </main>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.15/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>


</body>


</html>
```